# Unable to login to stackexchange sites using OpenID

Tags: support, openid, login, firefox

I've cleared my cache and history in Firefox and still cannot login to Stack Exchange sites (Super User, Stack Overflow, etc).  The error is the following:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.

- Using Chrome, I can no longer access any Stack Exchange site.
- Using Safari, I can l ogin to all Stack Exchange sites for which MyOpenID was already authenticated/related to.
- Using Safari, I cannot login to newly related Stack Exchange sites (I cannot follow-up on the question that was previously migrated).

Comment: @kiamlaluno: he is using MyOpenID - see here for more details: http://superuser.com/questions/283617/unable-to-login-to-meta-stackexchange-com-with-openid-but-can-login-to-other-sta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to stop using the convenient "log in with" buttons.  They used to work for me, but no longer.  Instead, click the link right below the buttons, "More OpenID options..."  then manually enter your full OpenID, for example http://your.name.myopenid.com When you are redirected to your OpenID host you should see the Username filled in.  Login as usual and you'll be redirected back to the stackexchange site.  (If you don't see the username filled in, showing the full openid handle, then the login will fail upon redirect back to the site)

Oh.  If you noticed studiohack's comment, you'll see why I wasn't responding.  This question was migrated, and I could not login.  After clearing cookies and cache I lost the ability to login to any stackexchange sites.  I was just about to create a new account with hope that I could then resume follow-ups to the issue when I found a work-around!

Comment: If you're having trouble with MyOpenID, consider [trying out the new Stack Exchange OpenID](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91039/help-us-test-and-vet-stackid-stack-exchange-openid) and help find bugs or other issues.

Answer (score 4):

This is frequently due to rogue plugins in my experience. Try in safe mode or in another browser to see.

edit: also, if you have an early MyOpenID account with a period in it such as

`foo.bar`

that will form

`foo.bar.myopenid.com`

which will cause problems for HTTPS. They no longer allow accounts with periods. If you have a MyOpenID with a period in it, **you *must* log in by manually typing the URL, you *cannot* log in by clicking the button**.

Comment: I guess that's what's happening to my account. Is there anything that can be done on the other side... to have an account without dots.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have issues too, and it is fixed by deleting all cookies related to stack overflow.

Switching to another browser essentially does the same thing.